# Spotfire - error message "The error information is not available anymore"

Tags: spotfire

When I am trying to access a Spotfire dashboard via web player, I am getting the below error message. I was able to access this dashboard earlier without any issues, this issue has popped up recently.

Please advise as what could be the reason for this error?

Below is the screen shot:[image]

Thank you!

Comment: Can you clear your cookies on that box and try to access it again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@scsimon/niko - Thanks for your suggestions. I was able to resolve this issue. Cleared cookies and tried to login again. I was able to login to dashboard but one of the pages was not loading. Duplicated page in client and deleted the old one. This resolved the issue.

Answer (score 1):

this error means that the data source has changed or is not available.

verify that your data source is still working in the Spotfire desktop client. check that the data source is either a linked DB table of some kind and that the information link still works. otherwise ensure any file-based data is embedded in the document.

the error seen on webplayer is pretty high level; it's basically "oh no, something's wrong!" and not very descriptive. if you can share some more including your Spotfire version and relevant logs (don't forget to remove sensitive data) I can probably give you a better answer.

Comment: @ niko - Spotfire version is 6.0.2.24

Comment: @ niko - Also, other users who are accessing the same dashboard, haven't encountered this issue.

Comment: @ksp585 without any logs I can't give you a better answer. can you edit your post and provide the logs please?

Comment: Hey Niko I had a tricky answer today and would like to get your thoughts. Let me know if there is an easier way. http://stackoverflow.com/a/39705317/6167855