# calculation the difference for same column for the specific rows in Spotfire

Tags: calculated-columns, difference, spotfire

I have a problem about the difference calculation for the rows using calculated column in Spotfire.

I am wondering if it is possible to create a calculated column that will count the difference between the current row with the next row which have different attribute. 
 A sample table could be like this:

[image]

the result could be like this:

[image]

the basic row is:

1. When **type**=1, then calculate the difference between its current **value** and its next nearest row which **type**=0, then add the result to a new calculated column.
2. btw, the VALUE is always increase :)
3. for example, for the first result *2*, current value is 20, next row is the nearest type with 0, and the value of next row is 22, then the result is 2
4. but for the next type=1, the current value is 25, and its nearest type=0 is on the sixth row, so the result could be 29-25=4

my method which i have tried:

1. i added a new RowID column
2. then try the code:

   ```
   if([type]=1),[value] - Sum([value]) OVER (PreviousPeriod([RowID])),null)
   ```

but it just show the difference between type 1, no type 1 and type 0 :(

Any help or suggestion would be greatly appreciated:)

thanks!

Comment: does VALUE always increase as new rows are added or can it decrease as well

Comment: Hi, the VALUE is always increase :)

Comment: Thanks for the information @Zawd

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Insert a column `RowId()` and name it `RowNum`
2. Insert a column with this expression :

`([value] - first([value]) over (intersect(previous([type]),AllNext([RowNum])))) * -1`

Here is what it will look like. I named the column `t1`. You can also ignore the `Val` column:

[image: Results]

**Explanation:**

The trick here is to limit the values in the `OVER` clause to those that will come after the current row. Furthermore, we want to get the first, next available value which meets our criteria. So, we take the first value, `first([value])`, that has it's previous `[type]`.This always be 0 since there isn't any negative values for `[type]`, thus this limits the rows we are working with to those with `[type] = 1` by using `previous([type])`. Now, to limit it to only the rows that come after the current row, we use `AllNext([RowNum])`. The `Intersect` statement states take the value where both of these rules are met. So looking at `RowNum = 4` it is evaluated like this.

```
[value] = 25
Previous([type])= 0 since current type is 1
AllNext([RowNum]) = RowNum that is > our RowNum which is 4, so tow numbers 5 - 7
The First([Value]) that meets these criteria is in RowNum = 6, which is 29 since it has [Type] = 0 and it's RowNum is > 4
Note, Row 7 also meets this criteria but it isn't the First() one.
Now, do the math... 25-29 = -4, and since you said the values always increase, we just multiply by -1 to get it in the format you wanted
```

Comment: I'm glad I could help @ZAWD   OVER functions were one of  Spotfires most difficult Expressions for me to learn so I try to be descriptive!

Comment: I am really new for it, i supposed i can learn it faster, but quite difficult to understand the syntax in a short time

Comment: hi, i just posted a new question about it, which i thought would be quite similar, pls refer to the http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39725348/matching-for-group-expressions-in-same-column-in-spotfire, when you have interest :)

Comment: i have found the main solutions for it, but has a small error :(

Comment: Nice @ZAWD i'm glad you found it!

Comment: i will look at your other question @ZAWD

Comment: thanks for it :) actually the solution is based on your idea which you have posted for this question :)

Comment: looks good, @scsimon! OVERs are a pain, even to explain to someone once you understand them, so nice job! :)

Comment: @ZAWD since you liked the answer could you award me the bounty before it expires? I also just answered your other question. You have some tough ones! Cheers!

Comment: Hi, thanks a lot for it, I thought i have award the bounty at the first day when u posted the answer :)

Comment: sorry, that i have checked it again ,so now, it could be awarded :) thanks agian

Comment: Hey no worries @ZAWD you have some fun, and very challenging questions

Comment: thanks for understanding, have no idea for the bounty rules. But this question have frustrated me these days...:(, will try your idea tmr :)

Comment: Ok let me know how it goes for you @ZAWD

Answer (score 0):

@ZAWD - Another way of solving this:

**Step 1:** Inserted a calculated column 'RowID' using the expression RowId()

**Step 2:** Inserted a calculated column 'test0' using the expression below

```
sum([Value]) over (Intersect(next([RowID]),Previous([Type])))
```

**Step 3:** Inserted a calculated column 'test' using the expression below

```
[Value] - sum([test0]) over (Next([RowID]))
```

**Step 4:** Inserted a calculated column 'myresult' using the expression below

```
Abs(If((Sum([Type]) over ([RowID])=1) and (Sum([Type]) over (Next([RowID]))=1),[test],[Value] - [test0]))
```

*Note: 'test0' and 'test' columns run in the background. They need not be included in the main table*

**Final table looks like below:**

[image]

Also, this solution works fine in whichever order the values are in. I have tested this solution with different scenarios and seems to be working fine.