# matching for group (Expressions) in same column in Spotfire

Tags: expression, calculated-columns, spotfire

Regarding the previous question which I have posted:
[calculation the difference for same column for the specific rows in Spotfire](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39662182/calculation-the-difference-for-same-column-for-the-specific-rows-in-spotfire/39705317?noredirect=1#comment66746001_39705317)

I have a new problem for it, below is the sample:

[image]

The new function that i want to realize is,

- searching for the ***next*** nearest TYPE=0 for TYPE=1
- if the TYPE=1 has nearest TYPE=0, then mark it as 'T' in a new calculated column, otherwise as NULL

Data Rules:

- **Status** column contains{1,2} in order, the default value of the null space is same as the last nearest Status value above it.
- **Type** column contains only 0 and 1 randomly

output should be like this:

[image]

the solution what i have tried:

```
    If(([type]=1) and (first([type]) OVER (intersect(previous([type]),AllNext([status])))=0),"T",Null)
```

it looks fine, but the problem is in each status group, for example the last TYPE=1(the 5th row) in the first status=1 group, it has not next nearest TYPE=0, so the judgement would be Null. But based on the code, it is T! :(

any suggestion and idea for it?
thanks a lot'!
PS: some details:

- the first Type Value of the status is NULL
- Other null space in the status column can be filled as below, if it is helpful for the expression :):

[image]

Comment: this one is tricky. Are the blank values in status and type null?

Comment: yes, but actually, we can fill the blank values with its latest status. :)

Comment: @scsimon, i added some details for the question, any further question is welcome :)

Comment: any feed back on the answers below?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, this one really tested my limits and I'm curious if it will scale. It works for your data, given where you have `NULL`. It took a few hours to figure out.

1. Insert a calculated column `RowId()` and name it `RowNum`
2. Insert a calculated column `RankReal([status],"ties.method=first")` and name it `Rank`
3. Insert a calculated column `If((first([status]) over (Previous([RowNum])) - First([status]) over ([RowNum]))=0,[Rank] - Max([RowNum]) OVER (Intersect([status],AllPrevious([RowNum]))))` and name it `GroupOfTypes`
4. Inert a calculated column `If([type]>Min([type]) over (Intersect([GroupOfTypes],AllNext([RowNum]))),"T")` and name it `Marking`. This is the row you really care about.

Results

[image]

**EXPLANATION**

`RankReal([status],"ties.method=first")`

This is done to essentially create a pseudo rownumber based on a segment of statuses. You'll see it ranks based on the status, sequentially. It's the first step in my method to group your data.

`If((first([status]) over (Previous([RowNum])) - First([status]) over ([RowNum]))=0,[Rank] - Max([RowNum]) OVER (Intersect([status],AllPrevious([RowNum]))))`

The first part of this, `(first([status]) over (Previous([RowNum])) - First([status]) over ([RowNum]))=0` is evaluating if the previous row's `[status]` column is the same as the current row. If it is, it returns a boolean `TRUE` value. If it is the same as it's previous row, we know that it belongs in the same block / grouping, so we do some math to label this column with the same value for the entire block. That is `[Rank] - Max([RowNum]) OVER (Intersect([status],AllPrevious([RowNum])))`. Therefore, each row within our grouping will equate to the same value.

`If([type]>Min([type]) over (Intersect([GroupOfTypes],AllNext([RowNum]))),"T")`

Lastly we evaluate if the `[type]` is larger than the mnimal `[type]` over all the next rows, based on the rownumber. This limits the data we focus on to those where `[type] = 1` without actually filtering the rows, while only looking **forward** in the dataset. If this is true we flag it with T.

Comment: really so sorry for the delay!!! have some problems that without any internet recently

Comment: No worries @ZAWD it happens. It has become a popular question as you can see :)

Comment: i was so surprised for it as well :)

Answer (score 1):

@ZAWD - Another way of solving this.

**Step 1:** Created a RowID using the expression RowId()

**Step 2:** Created a calculated column 'Mark0' using the expression below. This step is to find current type is not 0 and its consecutive type is 0.

*Note:This column runs in the background. Need not be included in the table. Also, 100 is some dummy value which is only used to ensure that the condition is satisfied*

```
If((Sum([type]) over ([RowID])!=0) and (Sum([type]) over (Next([RowID]))=0),100)
```

**Step 3:** Created a calculated column 'Mark1' using the expression below. This step is to find current type is not 0 and its consecutive type is also not 0 and Mark0 is filled.

*Note: This column runs in the background. Need not be included in the table*

```
If((Sum([type]) over ([RowID])!=0) and (Sum([type]) over (Next([RowID])) Is Not Null) and (first([Mark0]) over (allNext([RowID]))=100),100)
```

**Step 4:** Finally, created 'final mark' column using the expression below which marks 100 in Mark0 and Mark1 columns as 'T'

```
If(([Mark0]=100) or ([Mark1]=100),"T",null)
```

**Final Table:**

[image: nearest]
I have tested this with your data as well as different scenarios like three consecutive 1s in 'type' column instead of two and seems to be working fine. Please test it and let me know if this is stable.